# Can someone tell me what's wrong with this nested IF?

Tags: core-language, conditional

I have written a very simple nested `If` as follows

```
atom = be;


If[atom == li,
  lim = 5,
  
  If[atom == be,
   lim = 3,
   
   If[atom == b,
    lim = 2,
    
    If[atom == c,
     lim = 1,
     
     If[atom == n,
      lim = 0.5,
      
      If[atom == o,
       lim = 0.3,
       
       If[atom == f,
        lim = 0.1,
        
        If[atom == ne,
         lim = 0.05;
         
         ]]]]]]]];
atom
lim
```

but it works for `atom=li` namely just for first case, when I set `atom=be` for example it doesn't work and returns `lim` as unknown variable. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Use `Which` instead of `If`?

Comment: Thanks but I want to know why this doesn't work?!!

Comment: do you see any problem in my code?

Comment: Style of your code is very un-Mathematica, but the root cause of your problem is that `atom == li` evaluates to `be == li` which is neither `True` or `False`.  The correct approach is to use `===` instead of `==` on comparison.

Comment: If I were you, I'd consider some alternative approach, for instance
`atomlim = {li -> 5, be -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 1, n -> 0.5, o -> 0.3, f -> 0.1, ne -> 0.05};
atom = be;
atom /. atomlim`

Comment: @kirma Thanks, good idea

Comment: Why not use "li", "be" ... i.e. strings? `lim[atom_] := If[atom == "li", 5,
   If[atom == "be", 3,
    If[atom == "b", 2,
     If[atom == "c", 1,
      If[atom == "n", 0.5,
       If[atom == "o", 0.3,
        If[atom == "f", 0.1,
         If[atom == "ne", 0.05, 99]
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];` and `lim[#] & /@ {"li", "be", "c", "n", "o", "f", "ne"}`

Comment: @Syed because I had used them as iterator of an outer `Do` loop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change it to `===` and not `==` (examples at end)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
atom = be;
If[atom === li,
  lim = 5,
  If[atom === be,
   lim = 3,
   If[atom === b,
    lim = 2,
    If[atom === c,
     lim = 1,
     If[atom === n,
      lim = 0.5,
      If[atom === o,
       lim = 0.3,
       If[atom === f,
        lim = 0.1,
        If[atom === ne,
         lim = 0.05
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ];
```

And now

`lim` gives `3`

Compare the difference

```
ClearAll[be];
atom = be;
If[atom == li, "yes", "no", "can not decide"]
```

gives "can not decide" but

```
ClearAll[be];
atom = be;
If[atom === li, "yes", "no"]
```

gives "no".

In your original code, you had `==` which worked as follows (it did not evaluate)

```
ClearAll[be];
atom = be;
If[atom == li, "yes", "no"]
```

It did not evaluate, since it could not decide and there was no third argument to use for the result of `If`, so it returned unevaluated.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That is why your code did not evaluate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In general, can you tell me when should I use `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: @Wisdom The rule of thumb I try to use is this: When you are working with symbols with no values, using `===`. When working with things like numbers, strings, etc.. i.e. variables with actual values assigned to them, use `==` . Help says  `===` that `requires exact correspondence between expressions`. See help on `==` and `===` for more details. For example, if you want to check the `Head` is say `DSolve`, then using `===` and not `==` since this is symbolic equality (sameQ).  I think this topic is covered better in ....

Comment: ... [what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed comment, exactly I had used this code for numbers and it didn't had any problem and that is why I wondered it doesn't work here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative using `Switch`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
atom = be;
lim = Switch[atom,
  li, 5, be, 3, b, 2, c, 1, n, 0.5, o, 0.3, f, 0.1, ne, 0.05]
```

> 3

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method:

```
atomLim["li"] = 5; 
atomLim["be"] = 3; 
atomLim["b"] = 2; 
atomLim["c"] = 1; 
atomLim["n"] = .5; 
atomLim["o"] = .3; 
atomLim["f"] = .1; 
atomLim["ne"] = .05;
```

Then you can use `atomLim["be"]` which gives `3`. This code should be faster than using multiple if statements. It is also possible to make this more manageable when the number of elements gets large (I don't know if you're planning to implement the entire periodic table lol)

```
elements = ToString /@ {li, be, b, c, n, o, f, ne};
limvalues = {5, 3, 2, 1, .5, .3, .1, .05};
Do[
 atomLim[elements[[i]]] = limvalues[[i]],
 {i, 1, Length@elements}]
```

Comment: Instead of `Do` loop, you can also write: `MapThread[Set[atomLim[#1], #2] &, {elements, limvalues}]`